# detect the uniqueness of the usernames with Firebase and react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

In a registration form I have three fields

- Username
- email id
- password

When the user registers I need to verify whether the username is already taken or not . I am sending email and password for authentication and updating the profile with username . How can I check the username taken or not ?

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(createdUser => {
                    console.log(createdUser);
                    createdUser.user.updateProfile({
                        username: this.state.username
})
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that there is no `username` property for a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#properties). Consequently, passing an object with a `username` property to the [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#updateprofile) method will not work. You need to pass an object with the `displayName` and `photoURL` properties.

If you want to associate a **username** to your user, what you can very well do (and which is very common) is to have, in the Firestore database, a collection which contains a document for each user. You then store this username value in this document.

Then, to check the "username is not taken", you can query the collection before creating the user, as follows:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var usersRef = db.collection('users');
usersRef.where('username', '==', this.state.username).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
          return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    } else {
          throw new Error('username already taken');
    } 
  })
  .then(createdUser => {
       console.log(createdUser);
       //Create the user doc in the users collection
       db.collection('users').doc(createdUser.user.uid).set({username: this.state.username});
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  });
```

Comment: Any suggestion how would one setup Firestore DB rules for this? 

Problem I see is that one needs to allow access to `users` collection to unauthenticated users...isn't this a security issue? Is maybe there a way to only allow access to username property of `users/xyz` document? ...even this doesn't feel like a best practice to me, giving public a chance to see all of your usernames.

Comment: @Tadej Yes, there is an example of security rules in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication): look at the second code snippet (Introduced by "Another common pattern is to make sure users can only read and write their own data").

Comment: Right, I'm aware of that rule...but if you use it, `usersRef.where('username', '==', this.state.username).get()` won't work because user has no `uid` because he wasn't registered yet (he only get's UID in next then() statement)...so firestore throws exception about permissions.

Comment: @Tadej Oh, I see what you mean now! :-) If you want to check if a `username`exists but you want to allow users to only read their own profile you should use another way than the one presented in the answer. For example you could use a Callable Cloud Function to query the users collection. Or if you don't mind that usernames are public you could create another collection with documents that only contain the usernames.

Comment: right, I had the same 2 ideas in mind. I think using functions will be the cleanest way. Wasn't sure if it will work, but will try it and report back (all of the code needs to get wrapped in a transactions, so hopefully using functions won't cause problems).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can have a onChange event on username field which calls the api to know if the username already exists or not. And then in onSubmit you can validate if username is not taken you can submit the call.